# Low Poly Model Creation Workflow

Tags: workflow

Hi from a new total newbie blender user. I want to learn how to create at least “fine” low poly models, something like [here](https://sundaysundae.co/stunning-low-poly-art-images-you-need-to-see/).

I have heard that some people create high-poly models and then create low-poly models from them. Other people go straight for low poly.

Can you give me some links or just explain me a basic workflow for low poly model creation, please?

Comment: [Grant Abbitt](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZFUrFoqvqlN8seaAeEwjlw) is good in this area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood, low poly modelling means that you model your meshes using a very low number of polygons (not that you optimize your high poly model).

In this video you can see the workflow, it's very simple and fun:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YALV3HqfdLY

Basically this is the process:

- start with a basic shape, go to edit mode and edit it
- you can extrude, inset, bevel, loop cut, knife..
- proportional editing is also useful sometimes
- looptools' relax could be also a nice tool to learn
- color (with a simple palette)
- done!

Comment: love the video :)

Comment: Low poly can also mean optimized high poly models. You will see that terminology used often with models meant for game engines: a car or gun model labeled "low poly" which is completely unrelated to the flat-shaded low poly style. This was mentioned in my comment because of OP saying "I have heard that some people create high-poly models and then create low-poly models from them. " - this refers to what I was writing about.

Answer (score 1):

Low poly modelling seems to be easy and is easy then the realestic 3d stuff.  Now to begin with it you have to understand the basic shapes in your provided reference. Understanding shapes is most important so you can easily create similar loking shapes from your reference. Another part is look development which includes the lighting,  mood,  shader,  textures etc.

Answer (score -1):

When you hear about people using a high poly -> low poly workflow for their models, "low poly" is usually referring to, say, the type of model you would see in a video game: Realistic models with not too many polygons, using normal maps baked from a high poly model to keep some of the details. If you're making a stylistically low poly object, here are some tips: Take advantage of the Decimate modifier; you can sculpt something for example and decimate it to a low-poly object. It depends though, for structural and man-made objects, your low-poly should really just use primitives (cylinders, cubes, etc). For some details such as cracks in rocks, you can use the knife tool to cut out triangle-shaped wedges and delete the faces.

There are really a couple different styles I've seen under the general "low poly" category, but in general, I find that for organic objects like an animal or terrain, use tris/decimate to tris. For things like the lighthouse in your linked album, use a normal quad workflow. Lastly, remember that when adding primitives, a menu will pop up (or press F6) which allows you to lower the number of segments on a cylinder for example.

The main thing which determines whether low poly art looks good or not is just proportions. You don't have to focus on texturing, UV's or complex materials, so the basic shapes and outlines of objects are all that there is to focus on. This can just require alot of tweaking. There are tons of tutorials online; I would recommend Grant Abbitt's to start.

Comment: I don't think that low poly is what you are describing.. at least not the ones art references that the user posted.